# Windows 10 Stuck At Loading Screen After Adding HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot

recently I added a secondary [WD Blue 320GB HDD](https://www.cnet.com/products/wd-blue-wd3200aaks-hard-drive-320-gb-sata-300-series/specs/) to my system to accompany my [Seagate 320GB](https://www.cnet.com/products/seagate-momentus-thin-320gb-7200-rpm/specs/) drive. After I added the WD drive to my system I can no longer boot into windows, I just get stuck on the black loading screen with the Windows logo and the white spinny dots. If I unplug the secondardy WD drive it works flawlessly.

Have Tried:

- Different SATA ports on MOBO
- Accessing the recovery menu after 3 failed boots, but if I click anything the screen goes black.
- Removing CMOS Battery

PC Specs:

```
CPU: C2Q Q6600
GPU: GT 710
RAM: 4GB DDR2
MOBO: GIGABYTE GA-G31M-ES2C (REV 1.0)
HDD 1: Seagate Momentus Thin 320GB 7200RPM
HDD 2: WD Blue 320GB 7200RPM
```

Comment: Try the disk on another computer. It might be dead-on-arrival.

Comment: I have had the disk for quite a while and have used it in another build. I know it works perfectly fine, it shows up in the BIOS and everything.